# Using groupby,count and max in Python (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a beginner to panda and I am trying to use groupby on pandas.

My data has the columns age,gender,occupation and zip code

What I need to find is which occupation has more number of males than females and vice-versa

**Here is what I tried:**

```
df.groupby(["gender", "occupation"]).count().max(level=0)
```

The output comes as:

```
    age zip_code    status
gender          
F   60  60  60
M   136 136 136
```

But I want my output to look like:

```
gender  occupation  count
  F      student      60
  M      engineer     136
```

Can someone please help me with where I have gone wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use size() followed by reset_index(), for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender':np.random.choice(["M","F"],200),
                   'age':np.random.uniform(20,50,200),
                  'zip_code':np.random.choice(["A","B","C"],200),
                  'occupation':np.random.choice(["student","engineer"],200)})

df.groupby(["gender", "occupation"]).size().reset_index()

    gender  occupation  0
0   F   engineer    57
1   F   student     39
2   M   engineer    50
3   M   student     54
```